# Async HttpWebRequest - thread number

Tags: .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest, iasyncresult

Let's say I have the following code :

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100); 
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
 {
  //inside AsynchCallBack method for request.BeginGetResponse()
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);

  string html;
  using (var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
  using (var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream
                       , Encoding.UTF8))
  {
   html = readStream.ReadToEnd();
  }

            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

 }, null
 );
}
```

I'm expecting to see quite a lot of threads when writing to the console the ManagedThreadId - of course I am wrong :) . I generally see only 2 different thread Ids and once in a while 3 thread Ids.

Why this behavior ? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are hitting the [connection limit](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/1f863f20-09f9-49a5-8eee-17a89b591007).

Comment: Wow - that was fast :) . Thank you very much.